# How to power multiple LEDs and motion sensors on chair rail molding all throught the house

Tags: led, power-supply

I'm trying to connect multiple smart LED strip lights and motion sensors that will be installed inside the chair rail molding all throughtout the house. The LEDs will need a timer and remote control, mainly via apps. How can I power multiple LEDs having in mind there are some separators like windows, doors, appliances, where the LED strip stops and then starts again? I would like to do it in a nice way so that i don't have multiple wires and connections running around. This is mainly for older homes, with dry wall over studs, AC power is not available on every wall, and I would like to keep installation fairly easily (not tearing walls or major repairs).

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se]. If you'll take the [tour] and look at [how to ask a good question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask), you'll note that a question like "any thoughts?" is explicitly [off-topic](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) because it's far too broad and opinion based. If you'd care to [edit] your question to ask if a _specific_ setup would work or present us with a couple of options you've come up with asking for pros/cons of them, we can certainly answer that.

Comment: Is the idea that each motion sensor will control nearby sections of LED lighting? Do you need any additional control (e.g., remote, timer, etc.)? Is there AC power available in each wall (In the US, NEC requires generally a receptacle every 12 feet, but there are exceptions and older houses may not have that, etc.)? Are the walls drywall over studs (a.k.a., hollow walls, which allow relatively easy fishing of wires to new locations) or concrete blocks or something else?

Comment: You're going to need multiple drivers, because you're not going to be able to run that much light strip without voltage drop (and because you apparently have lots of gaps in the strip).  Do you have access to the top or bottom plates of the walls in question, like from a basement or attic?

Comment: Homes, plural? That may put it out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much the same way that outlets and lights are usually wired without anything exposed on the wall surface - put the cables connecting disparate sections **into** the walls, using suitable cable for in-wall application at low voltage (or in-wall cable suited for higher voltage, but used at lower voltage.)

If not done at build time this will require drywall repair (assuming the walls are drywall) and painting to permit running the cables in the walls. That's perfectly normal for *any* cabling retrofit that's concealed, as opposed to being exposed on the surface.

Comment: One possible idea in line with this answer is to remove the chair rail and the baseboard, and punch into the wall & fish for the low voltage wiring in the space behind the chair rail and baseboard. You might be able to avoid some drywall repair.